# How to get a list of installed external kernel modules?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, rhel, kernel-modules

From the documentation of Linux kernel 3.2 ([Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt))

```
=== 5. Module Installation

Modules which are included in the kernel are installed in the
directory:

    /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/kernel/

And external modules are installed in:

    /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/extra/
```

This implies that if I look into `/lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/extra/` I can find all installed external kernel modules. However, I find that the official Nvidia display driver installs `nvidia.ko` into `/lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/kernel/drivers/video/`. This contradicts the above rule and suggests that the path is not a reliable indicator of included/external modules.

How to get a list of external kernel modules installed? If the distro matters, I'd like to know the answer for RHEL 6 and Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 3):

For Debian/Ubuntu, something like

```
dpkg -S *.ko | grep /lib/modules | grep -v linux-image
```

should work. Disclaimer: I'm illiterate when it comes to pattern matching, so there are probably better ways of doing this. On my system, I get

```
nvidia-kernel-2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem: /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem/nvidia/nvidia.ko
nvidia-kernel-2.6.26-2-vserver-686-bigmem: /lib/modules/2.6.26-2-vserver-686-bigmem/nvidia/nvidia.ko
nvidia-kernel-2.6.26-1-vserver-686-bigmem: /lib/modules/2.6.26-1-vserver-686-bigmem/nvidia/nvidia.ko
```

This does assume that all installed modules are known to the packaging system, but this is generally a good idea anyway. At least on Debian, installing kernel modules as binary packages is generally possible. This approach has the advantage that it tells you which package a kernel module belongs to. Similar approaches should work with other Linux distributions which use a package management system; i.e. most of them.

Since the location of third party modules is similar to those of the in-kernel modules, it is not easy to distinguish them. Querying the package manager makes things easier. However, in my currently running kernel, in the directory `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem`, I notice that the nvidia modules are in a separate directory from the main kernel modules, namely `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem/nvidia` vs `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem/kernel`. I don't know if such a layout is Debian policy or not. The closest thing to Debian kernel policy I am aware of is [The Debian Kernel Handbook](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/), but I did not find anything relevant there. Of course, Ubuntu is not bound by Debian policy in any case.

Comment: Thanks! Your idea is to find `*.ko` that were installed with the package manager, but are not in the kernel package. On most systems, this probably gives an almost complete (if not complete) list of external kernel modules. Proprietary video card drivers are notable exceptions, but I can specifically look for them.

Comment: BTW, I found that on Ubuntu 10.04, the only packages (in the official repository) that contain kernel modules are the `linux-backports-modules` and `linux-image` packages. I used this command to check: `apt-file search --regexp '\.ko$' | egrep '^[^ ]+: /lib/modules' | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -c`

Comment: @netvope: Thanks for your comments. Actually, proprietary video card drivers are sometimes included in Debian/Ubuntu as well - see the nvidia module packages I list above. Ubuntu is much more enthusiastic about including them though. Also, there are many packages in both Ubuntu and Debian which dosn't have the structure you state. Are you sure you are searching all the repositories?

Comment: Looks like it's because those `nvidia-*` packages only build the modules when you install them. For example, `nvidia-173` (description = "NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library") contain a bunch of C sources and headers, but no `*.ko` files. Therefore, my previous comment based on `apt-file` results is incorrect.